Regex to match exactly ">>" in c#
I need a regex to match the characters double greater than (>>) in the string.
So if I have string such as Transaction Value >> 100, then I need to trim the content after >>. So final output should be Transaction Value. I am doing the below stuff but it trims if a single > is given which I don't want. I want to trim only if >> is there.
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var transValue = "Transaction Value >> 100";
var transRegex = new Regex("^([^>]*)");
var trimmedValue = transRegex.Match(transValue).Value.Trim();

Console.WriteLine(trimmedValue);


Try matching: \s*>{2}.*$ and replace with empty string. See: https://regex101.com/r/fn4KXl/latest

Why complicate it with Regex? Simple string.Contains(">>") may do the job. Put it as condition and when it's true - use string.Substring(0, string.LastIndexOf(">>") + 1) to cut off everything after ">>".

The RegEx of @DuesserBaest looks good, but be aware that you potentially have to set the multiline option of RegEx, depending, if you want to trim till the end of line or the end of text.

The answer of @Auditive is easier, but I would do a myString.LastIndexOf(">>") once and then check if it is greater or equal zero. Otherwise the source string must be scanned twice.

If you insist using Match, ^(?:(?!>>).)* should work

Try:
\s*>{2}.*$

an replace with empty string. See: regex101

Explanation

\s*: match any number of spaces preceeding
>{2}: exactly ">>"
.*$: and everything that follows until the end of line


If you want to match everything before ">>" use the aforementioned regex in a lookahead, like so:
^[^>]+(?=>{2}.*$)

See: regex101 alternative

Explanation

^[^>] match everything from the start of string that is not a ">" up until
(?=...)  looking ahead you see

>{2}: exactly ">>"
.*$: and everything that follows until the end of line




It works but it gives me the matched value as ">>100", whereas I need "Transaction Value".

@user3665818 My approach would be used in a replace method. If you want to match use the regex in a lookahead, like so: .+(?=>{2}.*$). See regex101.com/r/sZJXEk/latest

Thanks @DuesserBaest. This regex works fine. I think I missed to add a scenario in my question that if the string value is Transaction Value >>> 100, that is, 3 > then too it should get trim and return value should be Transaction Value. In short, if > appears more than once, the left hand side of > should be returned.

I will mark your earlier comment as Answered. Request you to comment on this scenario and then I would mark it as answered too if that works.

@user3665818 i am not 100% sure what you mean by this. See if the updated solution suits your needs.

I mean if the string is "Transaction Value >>> 100", your regex "(.+(?=>{2}.*$))" returns "Transaction Value >" while I am expecting it to be "Transaction Value" only. So irrespective of number of > occurrences in the string, it should always return "Transaction Value".

@user3665818 like so?

Like the below gives me "Transaction Value >" but I am expecting "Transaction Value" only.
var transValue = "OTC Transaction Fee with >>> than that";
var transRegex = new Regex(".+(?=>{2}.*$)");
var trimmedValue = transRegex.Match(transValue).Value.Trim();
Console.WriteLine(trimmedValue);

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There are a few alternatives that you can use:
Regex-based @">>"
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string pattern = @">>";
string input = "Transaction Value >> 100";
        
Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}", m.Value, m.Index);

Regex-based @">{2}"
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string pattern = @">{2}";
string input = "Transaction Value >> 100";
        
Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}", m.Value, m.Index);

(Bonus) IndexOf-based trimming
using System;

string pattern = ">>";
string input = "Transaction Value >> 100";

int patternIndex = input.IndexOf(pattern);
if(patternIndex == -1) {
    Console.WriteLine("The pattern was not found.");
    return;
}

string left = input.SubString(0, patternIndex);
string right = inpu.SubString(patternIndex + pattern.Length);

Console.WriteLine("left: '{0}', right: '{1}'", left, right);

These methods work because they return the index at which the pattern starts, meaning we can grab the left of the string by making a SubString from zero to whatever index the pattern is at.
*PS: If this answer is not fit for stackoverflow, I apologize in advance, I haven't posted answers in a while.

You can also add an option with string.Split(new string[] { ">>" }, StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries). If resulting array length > 1, then you can grab first element as "left".
